# explanation in following javascript code

Tags: javascript

I'll be really grateful if someone could explain me what the following code is doing. Being new to JavaScript I have only a rough idea of what it does. this will be a big help. Also please be forgiving if question is naive.

```
var init = function() {
    var box = document.querySelector('#theArt').children[0],
        showPanelButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#show-buttons input'),
        panelClassName = 'show-front',

        onButtonClick = function(event) {
            box.removeClassName(panelClassName);
            panelClassName = event.target.className;
            box.addClassName(panelClassName);
        };

    for (var i = 0, len = showPanelButtons.length; i < len; i++) {
        showPanelButtons[i].addEventListener('click', onButtonClick, false);
    }
};

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

this is the html code effected

```
 <div id="theArt">
<div id="cube" class="show-front">
  <figure class="front"><img src="../_images/feature1.jpg" width="270px" height="270px"></figure>
  <figure class="back"><img src="../_images/feature2.jpg" width="270px" height="270px"></figure>
  <figure class="right"><img src="../_images/feature3.jpg" width="270px" height="270px"></figure>
  <figure class="left"><img src="../_images/feature4.jpg" width="270px" height="270px"></figure>
  <figure class="top"><img src="../_images/painting01.png" width="270px" height="270px"></figure>
  <figure class="bottom"><img src="../_images/painting02.png" width="270px" height="270px"></figure>
</div>
```

```
<div id="options">
<p id="show-buttons">
  <input type="image" src="../_images/feature1.jpg" width="90" height="90" class="show-front"></input>
  <input type="image" src="../_images/feature2.jpg" width="90" height="90" class="show-back"></input>
  <input type="image" src="../_images/feature3.jpg" width="90" height="90" class="show-right"></input>
  <input type="image" src="../_images/feature4.jpg" width="90" height="90" class="show-left"></input>
  <input type="image" src="../_images/painting01.png" width="90" height="90" class="show-top"></input>
  <input type="image" src="../_images/painting02.png" width="90" height="90" class="show-bottom"></input>
</p>
```

Comment: [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded), [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: @RayonDabre i checked online , it is a javascipt dom that removes a class from the element... i think here it removes the class "panelClassName" from class box..... there is more on it in this link      http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/removeClassName/

Comment: @RayonDabre yes the code works fine.. i have used a modernizer with it.. my understanding of code is: var box is assigned first child of the id " theArt" , showPanelButton are all input ellements in id "show-buttons" and panelClassName is class "show-front" . idont understand the onButtonClick function.

Comment: this is the html code being effected:

Comment: `panelClassName` is removed from the `box` element..variable `panelClassName` hold the class of the clicked element..Class of the clicked element is added to the `box` element..

Answer (score 0):

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);

The above line is trying to add a event to the page when the DOM content loaded in the browser and the init function will get called. Init is the variable which has the function definition.

In function definition, variable box is trying to get the elements with ID "theArt". onButtonClick is the variable which has the another function definition.

showPanelButtons is the variable which will have all the list of element with id "show-buttons" with type "input". For loop is trying to add click events for every element in the showPanelButtons  list.

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

```
    //It is a javascript function
      var init = function() {
   //document.querySelector is a method which will return the first matched selector 
   //which is theArt in this snippet 
  //Selecting the first child none of #theArt DOM element and assigning it a variable
      var box = document.querySelector('#theArt').children[0],

     //document.querySelectorAll is another method which will return all matched elements unlike 
    //document.querySelector which return only single element.
    //showPanelButtons & panelClassName are variables.
   //This line selecting all input element which are inside DOM element 
    // with id show-buttons
     showPanelButtons = document.querySelectorAll('#show-buttons input'),
     panelClassName = 'show-front',

      //Could not find removeClassName function in your code or may be you are
      // using prototype.js
      //event.target.className will return the class on which the events have  
      //occured. For example click,keyup,keydown are events.
      //If you click on a button or input field and 
     //if you use  event.target.className it will return 
     //class of the button/input field
          onButtonClick = function( event ){
            box.removeClassName( panelClassName );
            panelClassName = event.target.className;
            box.addClassName( panelClassName );
          };

        //addEventListener is a method for attaching event to loop. 
       //Also look at scope of i if you want to accurately understand 
       // the usage of addEventListener  inside the loop  


        for (var i=0, len = showPanelButtons.length; i < len; i++) {
        showPanelButtons[i].addEventListener( 'click', onButtonClick, false);
        }

    };
    // DOMContentLoaded is an event .Here DOMContentLoaded is added to 
     //window object using addEventListener. 
//DOMContentLoaded event fires when the markup of a webpage has been 
//parsed.The last parameter in addEventListener (true/false) is used if you want 
//the event to capture or bubble up.
         window.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

Comment: it **should not** be `;` because here declare multiple variables in onw `var` statement. Otherwise other variables created as global

Comment: @Grundy thanks for pointing out. I have edited it.sorry I overlooked it while formatting